Search via Scopus API: how to limit publication type to journal articles?
I use pybliometrics.scopus to search for articles in peer-reviewed journals. One option (that works) is to set DOCTYPE to "ar" (article) or "re" (review). It is described in the guide https://schema.elsevier.com/dtds/document/bkapi/search/SCOPUSSearchTips.htm
However, that option seems unreliable, because it is document-based, and does not define explicitly which types are published in journals and which are not.
I found more straightforward approaches to limit search to journal papers in other guides: content-type(jl) and content(journal). However, they do not work (query translating error).
Is there a way to set explicitly that I need papers that were published in journals?

Answering for others who might land on this question in a web search:
Use SRCTYPE() when you want to select articles by the type of source, for example, SRCTYPE(j) returns documents from journal sources.
The following source types are available:

Book-b
Book Series-k
Conference Proceeding-p
Journal-j
Trade Journal-d

